# how can I calculate the p-value in R?

Tags: r, regression, p-value

how can I find the p-value of these regressions?

```
transphobia <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/umbertomig/intro-prob-stat-FGV/master/datasets/broockman_kalla_2016.csv")
trans <- subset(transphobia, !is.na(therm_trans_t0))

therm3.dummy <- lm(therm_trans_t3~treat_ind + therm_trans_t0 + vf_age + vf_racename + vf_female + vf_democrat + factor(canvasser_id), data = trans)


therm4.dummy <- lm(therm_trans_t4~treat_ind + therm_trans_t0 + vf_age + vf_racename + vf_female + vf_democrat + factor(canvasser_id), data = trans)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the summary output: `summary(therm3.dummy)` and `summary(therm4.dummy)`